# How do I properly link an OrthographicCamera to a OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer

Tags: libgdx, tiled, scene2d

how to properly link an OrthographicCamera to a OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer

How do I properly link an OrthographicCamera to a OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer? I have tiled map i'd like render and two stages that have actors on them.. I call render.render() in my screens render method as well as stages.draw(); but every i put render.setView(camera) the screen displayed flashes or does other weird things. How do I properly attach a moveable camera to a tiled map renderer? I render the map first, do game logic and then call draw on the stages. when I call translate on the camera the tiled map zooms way out for some reason?

here is my render method

```
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        renderer.render();





        gameLogic();


        backStage.act(); // acts are called but do nothing


        frontStage.act();

        frontStage.draw();
        backStage.draw();

}
```

here is where  the camera and renderer get created

```
public void addMap(GameMap map){

this.map=map;
maps.add(map);
    renderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map.getTiledMap(), 1/20f);
    camera= new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    float aspect = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 20*aspect, 20*aspect);


    renderer.setView(camera);
    frontStage= new Stage();
    backStage=new Stage();

    xSize=map.getXSize();
    ySize=map.getYSize();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

}
```

Comment: I solved my problem I took  someones working code   to make the camera move which was  100% the same as mine   made a new class tried running  it .  It worked!!  Then I slowly added  more of code  testing each time until I was 100% of my previous code that did not work.  The only thing I changed is I now have a new source code file (the class name is still the same though). Making a new class solved withe same code solved my problem?????

Comment: You must call `renderer.setView(camera);` in the render method so it will call every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem I took  someones working code   to make the camera move which was  100% the same as mine   made a new class tried running  it .  It worked!!  Then I slowly added  more of code  testing each time until I was 100% of my previous code that did not work.  The only thing I changed is I now have a new source code file (the class name is still the same though). Making a new class solved with the same code solved my problem?????